# Restore dump from older mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodump, mongorestore

I’m currently trying to restore a **mongodump** made with **mongodb:3.4-jessie** into a newer version, **mongodb:4.2.3-bionic**.

When I try to execute my command:
`sudo docker exec mongo mongorestore —db=mock —gzip /mongorestore/app`

It returns me with this error:

```
2020-05-01T00:01:29.405+0000    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2020-05-01T00:01:29.406+0000    Failed: mongorestore target '/home/user1/mongorestore/app' invalid: stat /home/user1/mongorestore/app: no such file or directory
2020-05-01T00:01:29.406+0000    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

The folder `app` contains `BSON` files and `json.gz` too.

I can’t upgrade the older dump, as it’s the only thing left and really want to use a newer version of mongo.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your command was blocked by problems before it could attempt to restore data to a newer mongodb release.

- You're running `mongorestore` inside a docker container but the input data directory `/mongorestore/app` does not seem to be inside the container (unless you mounted it in a previous step not seen here and passed the wrong path to `mongorestore`). You can use the Docker run command's `--mount` or `--volume` options to mount host directories into a container. Then pass its in-container path to the `mongorestore` command. See the [docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) docs.
- `mongorestore` is warning about this use of the `--db` option but it's not clear if that's because it can't find the input data directory or if it needs the `--nsInclude` option instead. See the [mongorestore command](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/) docs.
- You shouldn't need to use `sudo` with `docker exec`, and doing so could cause permission problems with the mounted output files. The `mongorestore` command shouldn't need `sudo` either, but if I'm wrong about that, write `docker exec mongo sudo mongorestore ...`.
- The mongodump and `mongorestore` docs suggest that the `--gzip` option expects all the files to be compressed, not just some of them. Maybe it notices each file's `.gz` filename extensions to decide whether to decompress it, but the docs don't say that it supports that case.

I'm betting `mongorestore` can restore BSON files from an older release. That file format should be very stable.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but with Mongo 5 and it worked like so:

```sh
mongorestore --host=hostname --port=portnum \
    --archive=/path/to/archive.gz --gzip --verbose \
    --nsInclude="mydbname.*" \
    --convertLegacyIndexes
```

where `mydbname` is the name of the db that I used when dumping the collections.

If you use another dbname now, then you need to convert them using `--nsFrom="mydbname.*" --nsTo="newdbname.*"`

All from: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/